# How do I handle purchases from iOS Settings app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am offering auto-renewable subscriptions (regular, premium and superb subscriptions with different prices) via iOS's in-app purchase. I have two questions to which I cannot find answers in the Apple's official documentation:

1. If the user cancels the subscription from the Settings app, as an App, how do I know the user has already cancelled the subscription so I can let my backend server understand?
2. If the user upgrades from regular to premium from the Settings app, how do I know this action so I can let the backend know?

Comment: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev0067a330b

Comment: 1. User's don't cancel subscriptions, they cancel renewal - So you simply won't get a renewal transaction at the end of the current period.  2. For upgrades your app will get a new purchase in the purchase queue next time it launches.  For downgrades, the renewal purchase presented to your queue at the end of the current period will be for the lower level.  You can also have your server subscribe to server notifications from Apple for these events.